# CRC32 calculation on Nucleo F4 and PC using python

Tags: python, c, crc32, stm32f4, nucleo

I have a Nucleo F401RE and want to use the integrated CRC module to make an integrity check on data being transmitted between the Nucleo and a PC using serial.

I've tried using this code to test if the CRC of the Nucleo matches the CRC on my PC:

Nucleo:

```
uint32_t test_data = 97;
uint32_t test_crc = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, &test_data, sizeof(test_data));
```

calculated CRC: 421584749

Python:

```
from crc import Calculator, Crc32, Configuration

stm32 = Configuration(
        width = 32,
        polynomial = 0x04C11DB7,
        init_value = 0xFFFFFFFF,
        reverse_input = False,
        reverse_output = False,
        final_xor_value = 0xFFFFFFFF
)

calculator = Calculator(stm32)

print(calculator.checksum(b'\x61'))
```

output: 429103979

Why is the output different?

CRC Init:

```
static void MX_CRC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CRC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CRC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CRC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CRC_Init 1 */
  hcrc.Instance = CRC;
  if (HAL_CRC_Init(&hcrc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CRC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END CRC_Init 2 */

}
```

Comment: Why should it be the same?

Comment: What happens if you use `calculator.checksum(b'\x61\x00\x00\x00')` or `calculator.checksum(b'\x00\x00\x00\x61')`?

Comment: In the first `sizeof(test_data) == 4`.  In the second, you're only CRCing 1 byte; although, with my CRC checker, I don't get the first answer for `00 00 00 61` or `61 00 00 00`, but I do match the 1-byte answer.  What is `hcrc` and was it initialized correctly?  Make a [mcve].

Comment: @mkrieger1 using ```(b'\x00\x00\x00\x61')``` puts out ```2426403236``` and ```(b'\x61\x00\x00\x00')``` results in ```3748425367```.

Comment: Those two answers match my CRC checker as well.  Either `HAL_CRC_Calculate` uses a difference CRC algorithm, or the unknown `hcrc` value matters.

Comment: @MarkTolonen 
The hcrc is the handle of the crc module. The HAL functions stores the configuration in the handle.

Comment: So how did you configure it?  Make a [mcve].

Comment: @MarkTolonen I added the autogenerated Init function in the question

Comment: Do you get the right answer if you use `uint8_t test_data = 97;`  Then only 1 byte will be CRCed.

Comment: @MarkTolonen If I do the crc with ```uint8_t ``` I get  ```1868564059``` decimal as Result

Comment: Then the CRC algorithm is different than the one you've implemented in Python.

Comment: @MarkTolonen The Nucleo uses the CRC32/MPEG2 algorithm. I've implemented that in my python script and now it works